# CYPHER storing count()-value for further usage

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I want to create a relationship between nodes that have one or multiple things in common and want to set the count of the common things as a property inside the relationship.

For example: in the movie-tutorial-graph I want to create a relationship between actors that have acted in the same movie(s) together and the set count of the movies they played in together as a property in the relationship.

For the basic counting, the tutorial provides a query:

```
MATCH (n)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coActors)
RETURN n.name, coActors.name, count(*) AS Strength ORDER BY Strength DESC
```

This gives me a list of 2 names and the amount of times they played in movies together (f.e. "Keanu Reeves", "Carrie-Anne Moss", Strength: 3 -> as there are the 3 Matrix movies inside the graph.)

Now I want to create a relationship (ACTED_WITH) between these pairs and set the strength-value as a property inside it.
I can create a relationship like this:

```
MATCH (a)-[:ACTED_IN]->(p)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(b) MERGE (a)-[r:ACTED_WITH]->(b)
```

MERGE ensures that there is only one relationship created, but I just can't get the counting-stuff to work with the creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [SET](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/set/) Cypher [clause](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/) to set properties on a matched node. If you try to set it in the [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/merge/) clause, than merge will treat the key(s) as a unique identifier, and will create a new relationship if one doesn't exist with that specific value yet.

```
MATCH (a)-[:ACTED_IN]->(p)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(b)
MERGE (a)-[r:ACTED_WITH]->(b)
// reduce matched set to one row of data
WITH DISTINCT a, b, r, COUNT(p) as strength, COLLECT(p) as movies
// set r
SET r.strength = strength
// Return everything to verify above results
RETURN *
```

SET will overwrite any previous value. If you want to only set it if you created the relationship, you can use [ON CREATE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/merge/#query-merge-on-create-on-match) or ON MATCH.

Comment: Update: one can delete the "COLLECT(p) as movies"-clause as it isnt used and causes the query to need more time

Comment: @Konster That bit is only included for verification purposes. After verifying the query is correct, you can remove that and the RETURN bits.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand what you want but maybe something like that:

```
  MATCH (a)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(b) 
   WITH  a,b, collect(m) AS movies ORDER BY size(movies)  DESC
   MERGE (a)-[r:ACTED_WITH]-(b)
   ON CREATE SET r.Strength=SIZE(movies)
```

Comment: This doen work completely. It somehow only creates the :ACTED_WITH-relationship between actors that have worked in only 1 movie together.
But thanks nonetheless.

Comment: Are you sure ? The following query `MATCH (a)-[r:ACTED_WITH]->(b) RETURN a.name, r.Strength, b.name ORDER BY r.Strength DESC` returns some results like the following `"Laurence Fishburne" 3 "Keanu Reeves"`

Comment: Yep, i tried it and it turned out as i described above.